# Sprockets with Sinatra: compile only changed files in development

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, sinatra, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm using a [boilerpale](https://github.com/l3ck/sinatra-boilerplate) sinatra app as a base for my sinatra application. It includes sprockets and a nice structure for the application. The server side is pretty simple and only renders a page which contains the code to start a single page backbone application.

The layout for the application is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <%= stylesheet_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_tag 'application', :expand => true %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= yield %>
</body>

<script>
    $(function() {
        ClientApp.start();
    });
</script>
```

In application.js there is a bunch of requires and require_trees:

```
//= require lib/jquery
//= require lib/underscore
//= require lib/backbone
//= require lib/backbone.wreqr
//= require lib/backbone.babysitter
//= require lib/backbone.validation
//= require lib/backbone.stickit
//= require lib/backbone.marionette
//= require lib/backbone.indexeddb
//= require lib/moment
//= require_tree ./backbone/config
//= require backbone/app
//= require_tree ./backbone/lib/entities
//= require_tree ./backbone/lib/routers
//= require_tree ./backbone/lib/views
//= require_tree ./backbone/lib/controllers
//= require_tree ./backbone/layouts
//= require_tree ./backbone/db
//= require_tree ./backbone/entities
//= require_tree ./backbone/apps
```

After the application starts it takes a long time to precompile all the assets and send them to client. After any change is applied to any coffeescript file it seems that sprockets recompiles all the files so refreshing a page in development is really painful. I've tried to set the debug flag for sprockets-helper but nothing changed. However the assets are served correctly file by file.

In the log file i can see that the first GET requests takes a logn time to be processed, but i can't really understand why i takes so long:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 14202 15.6592
"GET /assets/application.css?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0023
"GET /assets/lib/jquery.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0013
"GET /assets/lib/underscore.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0008
"GET /assets/lib/backbone.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0008
"GET /assets/lib/backbone.wreqr.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0007
"GET /assets/lib/backbone.babysitter.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0008
"GET /assets/lib/backbone.validation.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0011
"GET /assets/lib/backbone.stickit.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0010
"GET /assets/lib/moment.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0007
... Long list of assets
```

It looks like all the files are served fast as hell, what is that first call that takes more than 15 seconds?

Comment: If you refresh, does the `GET /` still take 15 seconds? It could be it takes your server a few seconds to start up.

Comment: @AJcodez If nothing is changed the next refresh is also fast. It's only slow on first start or when any file is changed